# Grid z-indexes and overlaps

Tags: html, css, css-grid, z-index

I have the following CodePen I'm working on: https://codepen.io/eliseodannunzio/pen/ZEyGvOy, which has a grid-based calendar set up, and I'm attempting to create a configurable dropdown. As I'm experimenting with CSS variables, I'm using a list of labels and radio buttons to pass specific values. I'll be setting up this list to be visible via a checkbox a little further down the line.

My concern is not the choice of using radio inputs and labels... but that the `input`s are being obscured by the calendar as seen within the CodePen. I find this strange as I've set up `z-index`es for the `input`s and `label`s as 10, which is higher than the values set up for within the `.calendar-wrapper` classed element and its children, which are all set with a `z-index` of 0...

Can anyone tell me what could be causing this glitch and how to render the CSS/HTML to ensure that this list of centuries overlaps the grid in the `.calendar-wrapper` element?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, the only thing you need to do is add

```
 position: relative;
```

for `label` elements, as z-index only affects elements that have a position value other than static (the default).

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/